# Run Checker Framework with Bazel

Tags: bazel, checker-framework

Consider this github repository. https://github.com/dfabulich/bazel-checker-framework-bug

It includes a sample `X.java` file that flagrantly violates the rules of the `@Nonnull` annotation.

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new X().exec();
    }

    public void exec() {
        System.out.println(this.method());
    }

    @Nonnull
    private String method() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `WORKSPACE` file just includes `checker.jar`.

```
maven_jar(
    name="checker",
    artifact="org.checkerframework:checker:2.3.1"
)
```

The `BUILD` file invokes the compiler with the checker framework configured as a `java_plugin`.

```
java_library(
    name='x',
    srcs=['X.java'],
    deps=['@checker//jar'],
    plugins=['checker'],
)

java_plugin(
    name='checker',
    deps=['@checker//jar'],
    processor_class='org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker',
)
```

When I `bazel build x`, the build fails with this error:

> error: InvocationTargetException when invoking constructor for class org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.KeyForAnnotatedTypeFactory; Underlying cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError; The Checker Framework crashed.  Please report the crash.  To see the full stack trace invoke the compiler with -AprintErrorStack

When I comment out the `plugins` line in the `BUILD` file, the build succeeds without error. (That makes sense, but I ultimately want the Checker Framework to fail this build with a `return.type.incompatible` error.)

Am I making a mistake here? Is this a bug in Bazel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a good answer on the [bazel-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/_ubd78wKw68), telling me to try [NullAway](https://github.com/uber/NullAway), an Error Prone plugin that depends on the Checker Framework.

The [github repo](https://github.com/dfabulich/bazel-checker-framework-bug) now includes a working example using NullAway, like this.

WORKSPACE:

```py
maven_jar(
    name='jsr305',
    artifact='com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2',
)

maven_jar(
    name="nullaway",
    artifact="com.uber.nullaway:nullaway:0.3.2"
)

maven_jar(
    name="guava",
    artifact="com.google.guava:guava:22.0",
)
```

BUILD:

```py
java_library(
    name='x',
    srcs=['X.java'],
    deps=['@jsr305//jar'],
    plugins=['nullaway'],
    javacopts=[
        '-Xep:NullAway:ERROR',
        '-XepOpt:NullAway:AnnotatedPackages=com.example',
    ],
)

java_plugin(
    name='nullaway',
    deps=[
        '@nullaway//jar',
        '@guava//jar',
    ],
)
```

(The dependency on guava is unfortunate; it's required because [without Guava, NullAway refuses to load](https://github.com/uber/NullAway/issues/119).)